# Mybatis mapper returns null value. in spring -rest-mybatis-mysql-gradle

Tags: spring, rest, gradle, mybatis, pojo

**{
"code": 1000,
"message": "Success",
"timestamp": 1596860735157,
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"contentName": null,
"createdTime": 0,
"contentPath": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"contentName": null,
"createdTime": 0,
"contentPath": null
},
{
"id": 3,
"contentName": null,
"createdTime": 0,
"contentPath": null
}
]
}**

here on t_content_library=>
id:bigint,content_name:varchar(450),content_path:varchar(500),created_time:bigint.

```
mysql> select * from t_content_library;
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| id | content_name                                       | content_path                                                                     | created_time  |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|  1 | pexels-jack-redgate-3014019.jpg                    | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\pexels-jack-redgate-3014019.jpg                    | 1596783953545 |
|  2 | pexels-thiago-matos-2335275.jpg                    | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\pexels-thiago-matos-2335275.jpg                    | 1596784207089 |
|  3 | louis-hansel-shotsoflouis-2gwghEzGp4g-unsplash.jpg | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\louis-hansel-shotsoflouis-2gwghEzGp4g-unsplash.jpg | 1596784491699 |
|  4 | jessica-delp-p1P_e86R2DI-unsplash.jpg              | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\jessica-delp-p1P_e86R2DI-unsplash.jpg              | 1596784579313 |
|  5 | patrick-untersee-OrT5-yC95j0-unsplash.jpg          | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\patrick-untersee-OrT5-yC95j0-unsplash.jpg          | 1596784602268 |
|  6 | jun-zhao-XWQ15ixxRjE-unsplash.jpg                  | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\jun-zhao-XWQ15ixxRjE-unsplash.jpg                  | 1596784616456 |
|  7 | jo-jo-mPM-x0zPhok-unsplash.jpg                     | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\jo-jo-mPM-x0zPhok-unsplash.jpg                     | 1596784632238 |
|  8 | melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg        | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\melnychuk-nataliya-8J6uuvsdj-4-unsplash.jpg        | 1596784644961 |
|  9 | nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg           | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\nathan-anderson-UhagOo7IOyc-unsplash.jpg           | 1596784877626 |
| 10 | gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg              | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\gayathri-sri-ptbKY_b1ROc-unsplash.jpg              | 1596784887985 |
| 11 | Depositphotos_95439918_xl-2015_1920x1920.jpg       | C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\content\Depositphotos_95439918_xl-2015_1920x1920.jpg       | 1596907309367 |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

1. model

   ```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @ToString
    public class ContentLibrary {
      int id;
      String contentName;
      long createdTime;
      String contentPath;

    }
   ```
2. controller

   ```
    @RequestMapping(path = "content/library/")
    @RestController
    public class ContentLibraryController {
    @Autowired
    ContentLibraryService contentLibraryService;

    @PostMapping("")
    public Response readLibrary() {
    List<ContentLibrary> contentLibraries = 
    contentLibraryService.readContentLibrary();
    return ResponseBuilder.buildSuccessResponse(contentLibraries);
    }
    }
   ```
3. service

   ```
    @Service
    public class ContentLibraryService {
    @Autowired
    ContentLibraryMapper contentLibraryMapper;

    ContentLibrary content = new ContentLibrary();

    public List<ContentLibrary> readContentLibrary() {
     return contentLibraryMapper.readAllLibraryContent();
    }
    }
   ```
4. mapper

   ```
     @Repository
     @Mapper
     public interface ContentLibraryMapper {
      @Select("SELECT 
      * FROM 
      t_content_library")
      List<ContentLibrary> readAllLibraryContent();
      }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution which is not the exact solution to implement a long list of columns. It is nothing but by adding a result set to map the result which is.

```
@Results({
        @Result(property ="id",column = "id"),
        @Result(property ="contentName",column = "content_name"),
        @Result(property ="contentPath",column = "content_path"),
        @Result(property ="createdTime",column = "created_time"),
})
    public List<ContentLibrary> readAllLibraryContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the MyBatis function that maps underscores to camel case.

If you are using Spring Boot, add the following to `application.properties`:

```
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
```

Comment: yes, I already added that mapper configuration and used to work with it for a while without any problem for a table t_user. but now it is clashing with response null value for other tables.